# Generic Try[T] function

Tags: scala, generics

I want to refactor some common error handling logic in a generic `Try[T]` handler, similar to this:

```
def handler[T](t: Try[T], successFunc: T => Unit) = {

  t.map {
    case Success(res) => { // type mismatch required T, found Any (in successFunc line)
    //case Success(res: T) => { // Type abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
      successFunc(res)
    }
    case Failure(e: CustomException) => {
      // custom actions
    }
    case Failure(e) => {
      // custom actions
    } 
  }
}
```

Seems I can't match against the type `T` because of type erasure. But I can't pass an `Any` to `successFunc`.

How can I implement this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mapping on a try applies a function to the value held by a success of that try, what you have there is not a `Success` or a `Failure`, it's a `T`, what you want is a `match`:

```
def handler[T](t: Try[T], successFunc: T => Unit) = {
  t match {
    case Success(res) =>
      successFunc(res)
    case Failure(e: FileNotFoundException) =>
    case Failure(e) =>
  }
}
```

The usage in your case of `map` would be:

```
t.map(someT => successFunc(someT))
```

Comment: Ahh, my bad! I This makes totally sense. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I like to return an explicit `()` to indicate a return type of `Unit`, i.e. `case Failure(e) => ()`. Also, I'd mark an explicit return type to `handler` of `Unit`.